# Using string and logic operators in if statements

Tags: java, string

I'm new to learning Java. I started about a week ago, and have spent around 10 hours a day learning, and I'm not sure if I'm behind where I "should be" (another concern I'm dealing with) 
I'm aware that my code is probably not the most efficient, but I have to start somewhere, and I've typed most of this out of memory from the cosmos of information I've read in the last week. Right now, I'm just trying to make games or apps to help solidify concepts of programming. To put what I've learned to use and make this information relevant.

my question is, essential, why are my "if" statements going directly to the "else"?

```
public class ClassSelect {

public static String className;

public static void pickPlayer() {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Pick your class." + "\n" + "[F]ighter" + "\n"
            + "[W]izard");
    String scanClass = scan.nextLine();

    if ((scanClass == "f") || (scanClass == "F")) {
        System.out.println("You picked the Fighter");
        String classNameF = "Fighter";
        className = classNameF;
        try {
            File file = new File("saveData.txt");
            BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            output.write(className);
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    else if ((scanClass == "w") || (scanClass == "W")) {
        System.out.println("You picked the Wizard");
        String classNameW = "Wizard";
        className = classNameW;
        try {
            File file = new File("saveData.txt");
            BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            output.write(className);
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("You didn't choose either.");
    }
}
```

Comment: On this site the RPG tag refers to a programming language.  Please read our tag info before using them.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For string comparison, you must use `equals` method of `Object` class. 
Your if statements will become like - `if(scanClass.equals("f"))...`

Remember, `==` compares reference and not the actual object.

Comment: Better yet if("f".equals(scanClass)){}

Comment: To improve it further: if("f".equalsIgnoreCase(scanClass)... saves you the more bulkish way of two compares.

Comment: Thank you, and everyone that answered. Sorry for such a noob question, but I honestly can't recall seeing "equals" in any of the online documents I've read, though I could be mistaken.

Comment: @Surlistyc If you feel your question is answered properly, you can accept the answer by clicking on right mark under down arrow.

Comment: @SajalDutta Agreed.:)

Comment: @LastFreeNickname My suggestion was for avoiding NPE, not for "bukish way of two compares"..not sure what that means.

Comment: @SajalDutta Exactly, that's why I gave your comment +1. It's an mistake made too often. My line was only to avoid if("f".equals... || "F".equals...).

Answer (score 0):

Always compare Strings using `equals`.

- == compares the references.
- equals() on the other hand compares the values.

  ```
  if ((scanClass.equals("f") || (scanClass.equals("F")))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using 
`scanClass.equalsIgnoreCase("f")` in if statements because `==` operator compares references not values.

Answer (score 0):

The operator, ==, tests to see if two object reference variables refer to the exact same instance of an object.

The method, .equals(), tests to see if the two objects being compared to each other are equivalent -- but they need not be the exact same instance of the same object. So

```
 if ((scanClass == "f") || (scanClass == "F"))
```

evaluates to false and control goes to the else block .